# Cocos2d-x high DesignResolution and iOS simulator display bug

Tags: c++, ios, ios-simulator, cocos2d-x, resolution

I'm currently building a game with cocos2dx 3.0 alpha0 in c++. At the moment I'm building for iOS.
I tried to set the "DesignResolution" at 1280 by 1920 (Which is double the iPhone 4 resolution) so I can have the graphics look good on iPad retina. Everything works fine on the devices but when I try to run it on the iPhone and iPad simulator I get three quarters of the screen rendered black. This happens whether it's iPhone, iPad or iPad retina simulator. When I tried to reduce the DesignResolution to 640 by 960 it shows fine on the simulator.
Does anyone have any information on this issue? How can I fix this rendering issue on the simulator?

Comment: It's best to set design resolution to the lowest supported resolution and use contentScaleFactor to scale up devices. I don't think design resolution is intended to be used for scaling down on lower resolution devices.

Comment: Hi thanks, I could use lower resolution images for a lower design resolution and scale up. If I wanted To have high quality images for the retina iPad I would then have a separate design resolution and resources for that but I would still get the same issue as my question. Thing is everything works on the device and displays fine. I'm just wondering why it acts differently on the simulator.

Comment: Turns out there was no problem, I had simply set positions of things during the accelerometers onAcceleration function. The simulator doesn't call this hence there was no display of a lot of things=)